# Why maxConcurrent setting in bottleneck.js doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rate-limiting

I'm using [bottleneck](https://github.com/SGrondin/bottleneck) npm package. I set my limiter as follows:

```
const limiter = new Bottleneck({
        maxConcurrent: 3,
        minTime: 100
});
```

to have 3 tasks running concurrently at most.
However, I see that at no time there're more than 1 task running concurrently.

This is my code:

```
const Bottleneck = require('bottleneck');

const main = () => {
    console.log('starting main');
    const limiter = new Bottleneck({
        maxConcurrent: 3,
        minTime: 100
    });

    const worker = (text, limiterCb) => {
        Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
            console.log(`starting ${text}`);
            let res;
            for (let i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
                res++
            }
            console.log(`ending ${text}`);
            limiterCb();
        });
    };

    const limiterCb = res => console.log('limiter finished');

    limiter.submit(worker, 'hello', limiterCb);
    limiter.submit(worker, 'hello', limiterCb);
    limiter.submit(worker, 'hello', limiterCb);
    limiter.submit(worker, 'hello', limiterCb);
}

main();
console.log('exiting')
```

What I see is that the first task starts and finishes, then the second etc. But because each tasks takes more than 100ms to finish I expected more than 1 task to be running concurrently.